# how to open web page in chrome browser by default in android

Tags: android

I try to open my web page as default in chrome  how could i do it .
MyCode Is:

```
       try {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.example.webviewdemo.MainActivity"));
            i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
             //exception raised
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Chrome is probably not installed
        }
```

When I run this activity not found exception shown error

Comment: do you have any web browsing appliation?

Comment: thanks first of all, sir my requirment is to open my web link in chrome browser  by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

```
internetIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.chrome","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
internetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Dude i Try This but i get 12-24 16:21:34.629: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.chrome/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-24 16:21:34.989: D/PowerManager(741): DVFSLock :  acquire

Comment: Using `PackageManger` and `Intent` you can check for specific intent category like, `Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE` is available for any application if available then set that application to `ComponentName`..read this, http://goo.gl/ZEd63I

Comment: thanks sufiyan but if i used this code then it will show me option to chosse browser which i do not want . i only want to open my weblink in chrome browser .